# What does apt's cache mean in apt-cache defination?

Tags: apt

What does apt's cache mean in the below defination?

> apt-cache is a command to manipulate and obtain information from the packages at apt's cache.

I searched a lot on this.. I get that there are lot commands under apt-cache which help us in getting/searching packages. But apt's cache!! What does it mean??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APT downloads packages information (with `apt-get update`) and stores them in a local database located at `/var/cache/apt`. This way, APT doesn't have to download something from the Internet every time you want, for instance, to search for a package.

That local database is APT's cache.